# -FIXED- cannot get / express and node js

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, openshift

hey guys im working on a project with some friends and we want our server on openshift it runs without errors but it always gives cannot get / 
i tried to look for solutions and tried many but it just doesent fix it.

any ideas ?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);


//


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));



server.listen(process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT, process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP);

io.on('connection', onSocketConnection);

var players = [];

var npc1 = new Player(1049, 980);
npc1.id = "Johan Kruijs";
npc1.color = "gold";
npc1.name = "[NPC] Johan Kruijs";

players.push(npc1);

function onSocketConnection(client) {
    console.log("Player has connected: ");
    client.on("disconnect", onClientDisconnect);
    client.on("new player", onNewPlayer);
    client.on("move player", onMovePlayer);
};

function onClientDisconnect() {
    var removePlayer = playerById(this.id);

    if (!removePlayer) {
        console.log("Player not found: " + this.id);
        return;
    }

    console.log(removePlayer.name + " has disconnected.");

    players.splice(players.indexOf(removePlayer), 1);
    this.broadcast.emit("remove player", {
        id: this.id
    });
};

function onNewPlayer(data) {
    var newPlayer = new Player(data.x, data.y);
    newPlayer.id = this.id;
    newPlayer.name = data.name;
    newPlayer.color = data.color;

    this.broadcast.emit("new player", {
        id: newPlayer.id,
        x: newPlayer.x,
        y: newPlayer.y,
        name: newPlayer.name,
        color: newPlayer.color
    });

    var i, existingPlayer;
    for (i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
        existingPlayer = players[i];
        this.emit("new player", {
            id: existingPlayer.id,
            x: existingPlayer.x,
            y: existingPlayer.y,
            name: existingPlayer.name,
            color: existingPlayer.color
        });
    };

    players.push(newPlayer);
    console.log(" - name: [" + newPlayer.name + "]")
    console.log(" - id:   [" + newPlayer.id + "]");
};

function onMovePlayer(data) {
    var player = playerById(data.id);
    player.x = data.x;
    player.y = data.y;
    player.id = data.id;

    io.emit("move player", {
        id: data.id,
        x: data.x,
        y: data.y
    })
};

function playerById(id) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
        if (players[i].id == id)
            return players[i];
    };

    return false;
};

function Player(xpos, ypos) {
    var result = {
        x: xpos,
        y: ypos,
        id: 0
    }
    return result;
}
```

[path --](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yX6E.png)

Comment: What URL are you trying? You don't have a route set up for `/`

Comment: im trying to load the index.html that is in my public folder on local server it works just fine so i dont know

Comment: And if your URL is `/index.html` what happens?

Comment: Cannot GET /index.html        i can post all the code of server if you want

Comment: And if you load `/static/index.html` ?

Comment: Cannot GET /static/index.html

Comment: Do you use `app.router` or any other routes other than the one you've posted?

Comment: app.router ? ill update the code in the question

Comment: It looks like path to `public` folder is not correct, could you update the question with screenshot or text-scheme of folder structure of your app?

Comment: FIXED : i needed to go to static with capital

Comment: Also if you wanna set default file, for `/` you can look at the my answer below ....

Comment: When you have solved the problem, please accept an answer, or write an answer telling what you have done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the screenshot you shared, the folder name is `Public` and not `public`, in osX (I assume that is what you are using from the screenshot), `Public` and `public` are different.

If you write this,

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/Public'));`

Things should start working.

Plus if you wanna set a default page, i.e. when user visits `/` and you want your `/index.html` to be served, you can do it like

`app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/Public', {index: "index.html"}));`

I hope this resolves your issue!!

Comment: thanks :)  i got the project files on my mac from my windows pc so thats probably why i dident notice

Comment: Happens to be best of us! Working cross-platform is a challenge in itself... :) keep up the good work!